# Error when adding data to the database

Tags: c#, mysql

```
//Query SQL
MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Equipamento (equipamento, situacao, modelo, nr_serie, avaria, estado_equipamento, data, estado_reparacao, reincidente, ID)" +
"VALUES(@equipamento, @situacao, @modelo, @nr_serie, @avaria, @estado_equipamento, @data, @estado_reparacao, @reincidente, @id)", mConn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@equipamento", comboequipamento.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@situacao", "Em diagnóstico");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelo", tbmodelo.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr_serie", tbserie.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avaria", tbavaria.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado_equipamento", tbestado.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado_reparacao", null);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reincidente", 0);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbid.Text);

//Executa a Query SQL
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
Atribuir_IDFicha();
```

I have this code, it used to work until I got it parameterized:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())`?  That's converting a `string` to a `string`...

Answer (score 3):

Your `MySqlCommand` variable is called `command1`, but you are adding the parameters to `command`.